# iOS app crashes when setting alpha property of custom view

Tags: ios, animation, view, alpha

I'm trying to set the alpha property of a view in an animation block but every now and then (no pattern determined) the app will crash with no errors on the line of setting the alpha to 0:

```
self.circularProgressBar.alpha = 0
```

CircularProgressBar is a view with a couple of CAShapeLayers, but I want to animate hide the whole thing. When I inspect the crash in the console, I can access the .alpha property, as well as update it. It works most of the time, it just fails at some point for some reason..

It's also running in the main thread which I thought may be an issue, but it seems not.

Any ideas why/how to diagnose what it could be?

Comment: make sure the views opaque property is set to NO (false). I think in swift it's named isOpaque. the default is YES (true)

Comment: show the crash log

Comment: I don't see any crash logs. Nothing appears in the console and only returns the following on the line it crashes - EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_i386_CPFLT).

Would you advise of anywhere else to look for a helpful crash log?

As I say, it's odd because even after it crashes, I can still access the view and also the .alpha property so not sure what it is failing on exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was crashing at the call to alpha wasn't being called in the main thread. In this scenario there is a background task uploading a file and the alpha is when the upload finishes to hide a progress bar.

Checking and tidying up the threads seems to have fixed this issue.